# как работает json?

Tags: python, json, кодировка

```
f = open('json_data.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') # открывает файл для записи
json.dump(str(items), f)
f.close()
```

в файле json_data.txt, появляется много данных разделенных "\".

Например:  `"title":"Холодильник Side by Side"` в файле записана как: `"title\":\"\u0425\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043b\u044c\u043d\u0438\u043a Side by Side\"`.

Мне нужно по ключу "title" в словарь записать все значение, одно из них "Холодильник Side by Side ".

Но в странице,которая парсится, в месте где этот текст, нет HTML тегов. Там ДжаваСкрипт генерирует страницу. Поэтому применяю json. Но не понятно как данные по определенному ключу в словарь записать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте в [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) сам объект, а не его строковое представление.
А чтобы русские символы отображались как есть, то указывайте `ensure_ascii=False`

Пример:

```
with open('json_data.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(items, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```